# Can I trust that "required" input elements have values submitted?

Tags: php, html, required

Can I trust the required attribute for my fields in a form?

```
<input type="text" name="username" required/>
```

The above code will ensure that it is a required field, but couldn't the user just inspect element and remove the attribute? Is it necessary that I check `if (isset($_POST...` or can I rely on the required attribute to do it's thing?

Comment: You can never trust anything that's done on the client. There's no reason to assume that the POST comes from a web browser, it could be a script.

Comment: Yes, a user could remove the attribute via the console. You should always validate server side as well as client side. Client side validation should be considered as a niceity to make the process more enjoyable, but shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: Older browsers didn't even have a required tag, so an older browser would get past that as well.

Comment: It's "thing" is to warn the user that you have a constraint that will fail once it's submitted. Hence, in some browsers *it will do it's thing* (given the right browser/version) and warn the user they're about to make a mistake, but *your* thing is to first validate on the server anything submitted by the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use server side validation. The required attribute exists on the front end and can be easily manipulated if a malicious user wishes to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

required property is added in html5, works with most browsers, the problem, as always, is that ie does not work, and other older browsers, therefore, would not trust that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Validation should always be done on server side. There are things like `interception proxy` that can bypass even Javascript validation. So you can't even use Javascript for validation purposes. You can use these to inform users that these fields are required but depending on them is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Server side validation is your best bet.  Currently Safari on desktop and iOS, as well as Android browsers, do not support the "required" attribute of any input type as a means of submission validation (though the pseudoclass css selector is supported, strangely).

reference: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html